# Map v2 SupportMapFragment inside Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-maps

**Background**

I have successfuflly added the new map api v2.0 to a ViewPager and the map loads fine. I am using the FragmentViewPager. I run into trouble however when trying to add markers as I cannot get the Fragment by tag as the ViewPager I am using is from the compatibility library and defined in XML, and this "hides" the tag from me.

**The Question**

How can I load the new Map v2 with markers `SupportMapFragment` into a `ViewPager` that uses a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

**My Attempt**

So in my nievety I thought could create an elegant solution by extending the SupportMapFragment into a new class that does the following:

1. Add a new constructor that takes `GoogleMapOptions` and `List<MarkerOptions>` . This effectively calls the existing constructor that just takes `GoogleMapsOptions` and then store my list of markers inside a private property of the new class.
2. Override `GetMap()` - check if it is null and if it is not add the markers to the map that we loaded earlier on to the map and finally return it.

My thoughts were that my extension could be highly reusable and abstracts anything map related to one place and allows my activities to create the new MapFragment by `newInstance(myGoogleMapOptions, myMarkers)`.

Ok so the issue. Part 1 seems to work fine however during debugging I cannot get the overridden GetMap() method to be called. In fact I have tried overriding most of the usual methods that fragments have and none of them get called. Is there something weird going on with the SupportMapFragmemt, I tried to find the source for it to no avail to check for myself.

**Update**

I realised why I wasn't getting my overridden methods called. It was because I was returning the standard `SupportMapFragment` rather than `MyMapFragment`. That said I cannot call super from a static method and I cannot cast from a base class to a derived class without exception.

**Edit**
Here is the class

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    private static List<MarkerOptions> mMarkers;

    public static SupportMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options, List<MarkerOptions> markers)
    {
        SupportMapFragment fragment = newInstance(options);

        mMarkers = markers;

        return fragment;

    }

            //have tried Overriding several methods including getMap()...

    @Override
    public void onResume ()
    {
        GoogleMap mMap = super.getMap();
        //add the markers
        if(mMap != null)
        {
            for(MarkerOptions marker : mMarkers)
            {
                mMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I will post my attempt in the morning as code is on work machine.

Comment: no I haven't unfortunately and I doubt I am the only one who may face this problem.

Comment: i am trying to do the same inside a tab host stuck with a null pointer exception

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just tried like this and it works.

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    private List<MarkerOptions> mMarkers;

    public static MyMapFragment create(GoogleMapOptions options, ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers) {
        MyMapFragment fragment = new MyMapFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("MapOptions", options); //obtained by decompiling google-play-services.jar
        args.putParcelableArrayList("markers", markers);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hacky and ugly but it works
        ArrayList<Parcelable> list = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("markers");
        mMarkers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>(list.size());
        for (Parcelable parcelable : list) {
            mMarkers.add((MarkerOptions) parcelable);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        GoogleMap mMap = super.getMap();
        //add the markers
        if (mMap != null) {
            for (MarkerOptions marker : mMarkers) {
                mMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great! I am in another city over the weekend but I will try to get it tested asap. Just annoys me slightly that Google did not think to add this option seeing how little time it took once once the functionality of 'newInstance()' was known.

Comment: Your a lifesaver. I've spent an hour trying to add GoogleMapOptions().zOrderOnTop(true) to a MapFragment subclass. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how i can use this?

Comment: I have tried your code, have lot of doubt where i have used this, Can you please add the reference code or link how to implement in step by step, because in my view pager i have one list view and map, and have to toggle the map and list by using button in single button. please help me bro.