# Google Maps v2 SupportMapFragment inside a Fragment into an Activity with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, gps, location

I'm working to an app that uses a **map with the user's current location**. I've designed the UI following the standards of Android platform (reference: Android Developers/Design), so I'm trying to **insert a GoogleMap into a Fragment within an Activity that contains a Navigation Drawer and four Fragments**.
The problem is that in the web I found only solutions that matches for the case I use an Activity (e.g. a fragment inside Activity XML layout), but it isn't what I desire!
I want to insert only a map (with current location) in a Fragment, possibly using SupportMapFragment (I want in fact that my application works on **Gingerbread+**).
I've tried to insert only a map follow a tutorial in the web (I don't remember the link, sorry), but it was impossible to customize it.

For a major comprehension, I attach some piece of code:

**MainActivity.java** (that contains a NavDrawer and 4 Fragments)

```
public class MainActivity extends AbstractNavDrawerActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MapFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**MapFragment.java** (Fragment in which I want to insert a working map with position)

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    // Argument representing the section number for this fragment.
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static MapFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**fragment_map.xml** (Map layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView" />
```

I ensure that GoogleMaps works correctly, the example tutorial that use an Activity with a Map works well. I've read some solution here, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735124/map-v2-supportmapfragment-inside-viewpager?rq=1), but it doesn't works in my case!

Anyone can help me?

Thank you very much indeed guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your MapFragment use the following code

```
 GoogleMap map=((MapFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 

 if(map!=null){ 
     map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)) // latitude and longitude info is given here
     .title(TITLE)); // title for the marker
 }
```

In your layout file create a fragment for displaying the map

```
<fragment
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Comment: It doesn't works. I insert the java code into onCreateView but "getActivity()" isn't correct because i work into a fragment. I replace that lines with "GoogleMap map=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();" but it doesn't works alike.

Comment: what error are you actually getting ...? this code works perfectly in a fragment